# Run GWT shell normal, use -noserver on compile?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I would like to run the GWT shell (the nice little Google pop-up browser window) when "testing" and upon clicking the actual "Compile/Browse" on the tool, compile the program into a different directory and use the -noserver mode to test it on my IIS server.

Problem:

I have not edited the normal shell script, so it fires off just fine.  The edits I make are viewed upon refreshing.  The compile/browse however, shoots me off to mini-Tomcat server instead of my directory.  The compile DOES appear to be running (as I can browse to that directory directly and it is receiving updates), but the compile/browse does not shunt me there.

Here is the compile script I've got right now:

```
@java -Xmx256M -noserver -port 80 -cp "%~dp0\src;%~dp0\bin;C:/dev/gwt-windows-1.5.3/gwt-user.jar;C:/dev/gwt-windows-1.5.3/gwt-dev-windows.jar" com.google.gwt.dev.GWTCompiler -out c:/dev/Practice /Practice/Practice.html
```

Clearly the area I would LIKE to go is "http://localhost/Practice/Practice.html" (the IIS server) but it is jumping to "http://localhost:8888/practice.Practice/Practice.html" (the Tomcat server).

Ideas?

(P.S. Running Eclipse for editor, the Run/Debug config arguments are:

```
practice.Practice/Practice.html
```

and that's it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an Eclipse run profile for the GWTCompiler class. One of the arguments you pass in is the path to compile to, so you could run the compile from Eclipse and it would write the files directly to the IIS's folder if you specified it. Once the compile is done, you can use the already open Hosted Mode instance and just type in the http://localhost/Practice/Practice.html path, and it'll work.

The Hosted Mode browser can be pointed at any server even without running it with -noserver, and if you get security warnings about leaving the domain, you can add a -whiteList argument to the Hosted Mode run profile. The security warnings will give you an example whiteList argument.

Try running GWTCompiler and GWTShell with no arguments for the possibilities. I'd be more detailed, but I don't have a dev environment with me right now.

Comment: Ah thanks, that pretty much sums up my issues in a nutshell, was just going to mark my own answer too.